# Scala Slick 2.0: converting from Query[Mixed, T#TableElementType] to Query[T, T#TableElementType]

Tags: scala, slick

Assume we have a table

```
class Entry(tag :Tag) extends Table[(String, Long)](tag, "entries") {
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def value = column[Long]("value")
    def * = (name, value)
}
val Entries = new TableQuery(new Entry(_))
```

and a query of type `Query[(Column[String], Column[Long]), (String, Long)]`. Can I somehow convert it to `Query[Entry, (String, Long)]`? This would be very useful in case of grouping queries such as `Entries.groupBy(_.name).map(g=>(g._1, g._2.map(_.value).avg))`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
case  class Entry(name: String,value: Long)

class Entries(tag :Tag) extends Table[Entry](tag, "entries") {
   def name = column[String]("name")
   def value = column[Long]("value")
   def * = (name, value) <>(Entry.tupled, Entry.unapply )
 }
val Entries = TableQuery[Entries]
```

Comment: The actual TableElementType has nothing to do with it. The result of the above groupBy is still the same.